# PrototypeJS to jQuery | document.viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm trying to convert some prototype code to jQuery.

I have these calls that I don't know the how to convert:

```
document.viewport.getHeight();
document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().top
```

#### Question

What's the equality for the above code in jQuery?
If there is none, what is the vanilla way of doing it?

Comment: [jQuery has documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern browsers:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight
document.documentElement.scrollTop
```

In jQuery:

```
$(window).height();
$(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: how about `document.viewport.getScrollOffsets().top`?

Comment: there is no jQuery way for it?

Comment: @ErikLandvall In case you're interested, I've added a vanilla javascript way as well.

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen Why would you suggest document.body.offsetHeight and not document.documentElement.scrollTop? That seems like a worse solution to me.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `document.body.offsetHeight` is meant to get the window height, not the scroll position; *Retrieves the height of the object relative to the layout or coordinate parent, as specified by the offsetParent property.*

Comment: Right, that was a clear copy-paste error, I meant document.documentElement.clientHeight

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `documentElement.clientHeight` has mixed results across browsers. In some browsers it refers to the `document`, in others it refers to the `window` object. `body.clientHeight` has the most consistent behavior across browsers. [Reference here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow).

Answer (score 2):

### jQuery way

Window [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
$(window).height();
```

[Scroll top](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
$(window).scrollTop();
```

### Vanilla javascript way:

Window height

```
var winHeight = 0;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
    winHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' && document.documentElement && document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
    winHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerHeight) {
    winHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Scroll offset:

```
var scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
```